# Change UITextField height in UISearchBar - Swift 3

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uisearchbar, swift3, xcode8

is there a way to change the height of a UISearchBar's textField??

I can access the textField like this and although background color changes, nothing seems to change in terms of frame/size...

I was able to change the searchBar height in IB by setting the constraints.
But the textfield stayed the same (44)...

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        self.mySearchBar.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.mySearchBar.layoutSubviews()
        self.mySearchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        for subView in mySearchBar.subviews
        {
            for subsubView in subView.subviews
            {
                if let textField = subsubView as? UITextField
                {
                    var currentTextFieldBounds = textField.bounds
                    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.none
                    currentTextFieldBounds.size.height = self.mySearchBar.bounds.height-10

                    textField.bounds = currentTextFieldBounds

                    textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The `UITextField` within the `UISearchBar` is not directly accessible. You could create your own `UISearchBar`subclass to emulate a regular Search bar. You could completely customize the UI as you see fit with either Interface builder or programatically.

```
protocol SearchBarEventDelegate {
    func searchButtonPressed(searchBar: CustomSearchBar)
    func searchBarDidReceiveInput(searchText: String)
    func searchBarDidBackspace(searchText: String)
}

class CustomSearchBar: UIView {

    var searchTextField: UITextField?
    var delegate : SearchBarEventDelegate?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(searchTextField())
    }

    func searchTextField() -> UITextField {
        //Input custom frame and attributes here.
        let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRectZero) 
        textField.delegate = self
        return textField
    }
}

extension CustomSearchBar : UITextFieldDelegate {
     //Implement Textfield delegate methods here. 
     //Propagate events to CustomSearchBar delegate. Example Provided.
    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let partialSearchString = textField.text!
        let fullSearchString = (partialSearchString as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

        if(range.length == 1) {
            delegate?.searchBarDidBackspace(fullSearchString)
        } else {
            delegate?.searchBarDidReceiveInput(fullSearchString)
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. I cannot accept the answer though as there are numerous errors in when trying to implement in Swift 3.